# What is the meaning of $\{0, 1\}^{L}$?

Tags: notation, cryptography

I've searched for this but suspect I don't know what to call it, so of course can't find information on it. I'm reading through a text that includes this:

$$C := \{0,1\}^L$$

I'm not sure what the exponent $L$ indicates here.

Comment: I can’t be certain without more context, but most likely it is the set of functions from $L$ to $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: Equivalently, vectors of length $L$ where each component is 0 or 1.

Comment: Very bad title. Not informative.

Comment: Which text are you referring to?

Comment: Dan Boneh and Victor Shoup's crypto book: https://toc.cryptobook.us/book.pdf Example one on page four.  Sorry about the bad title; I'm not familiar enough with the terminology to conceive of something better.  Messrs. Scott and Pratt, thank you for the help.

Comment: I ended up finding out it's the set of all L-bit strings, so the expression says the ciphertext is defined as all those.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: @bin Please *edit your question* to include the source you described in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

$L$ is the length, the set $\{0,1\}^L$ can be seen as all words consisting of bits of length $L$. (given the crypto-context, not unusual), so it looks like the ciphertext space (the possible values of a ciphertext) are such bit strings.